# Invalid argument : No Host specified in URI file:/// (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have created this UI in flutter and firebase which is similar to instagram .when i upload a photo it show error "Invalid argument: No host specified in URI file:///null" .In below image i have shown the action button which is used to upload media to firebase.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      final selectedMedia = await selectMedia();
      if (selectedMedia != null &&
          validateFileFormat(selectedMedia.storagePath, context)) {
        showUploadMessage(context, 'Uploading file...', showLoading: 
        true);
        final downloadUrl = await uploadData(
            selectedMedia.storagePath, selectedMedia.bytes);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
        if (downloadUrl != null) {
          setState(() => uploadedFileUrl = downloadUrl);
          showUploadMessage(context, 'Success!');
        } else {
          showUploadMessage(context, 'Failed to upload media');
        }
      }

      final postsRecordData = createPostsRecordData(
        photoUrl: uploadedFileUrl,
      );
      await PostsRecord.collection.doc().set(postsRecordData);
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    elevation: 8,
  ),
```

[image: Picture of my UI]

Comment: Is `uploadData` your own function?  If so, where is the code to that?  If not, where is it from?

Comment: i have created this app using flutter flow so ,all the functions used here are from flutter flow .